# When to create a new class / arrayList vs. when to just rely on the database under MVC practices

Tags: java, android, sqlite, model-view-controller, arraylist

I am trying to follow Model-View-Controller practices for learning app development.

Right now I am having trouble figuring out how to balance between storing things in a database vs. a class in relation to viewing/processing.

For example my app lets you create profiles. I have a SQLite database that holds all the names in a table.

However this feels funny to me. For example if I want to populate a `ListView` with the profile names, I have to create an `ArrayList<String>`, populate it with the profile names from the database (via cursor), and then set it via `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

Maybe this is all fine and well, but it feels funny to me because I don't use something like a `Profile` class. Right now such a class would only hold a `private String mProfileName` and have some getters/setters, but is this class not needed if I already have the database storing everything?

I'm confused as to whether or not I should have a `private ArrayList<String> mProfileNames` member variable in my activity class, or if I should aim for a `private ArrayList<Profile> mProfiles` member variable in my activity class instead, or if it's not necessary to have such an arraylist in the first place since all that data is in the database so I only need to instantiate an arraylist in the function where I use it with the adapter/listview-setting, etc.

Because if I do have a private member variable holding all these names *in addition* to the database, then I have to worry about making sure that any time I update the database in any way (adding/removing/etc), I also update the arraylist in the same way, and this feels like a bad practice / risk for some reason.

Or maybe I use a Profile class to encapsulate the SQL functions instead of my activity?

I could really use some pointers in the right direction to properly implement MVC practice in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a SQLite database that holds all the names in a table.

So, you have a `SQLiteOpenHelper` that creates a Table of "profile names".

A `Profile` object *could* be used to encapsulate the data, but it is not necessary if you only have one column.

If you were to add more data, though, doing `cursor.getColumnValue(0...n)` for all `n` columns every time you read the data out of the table is not a good practice.

Having a static method of `Profile p = Profile.fromCursor(cursor)` makes that cleaner, and then you can use `String name = p.getName();`, for example, for all the instance variables of `Profile`. After that, you have a full object that you can modify and define a method like `profileDBHelper.upsert(p);` to do an insert or update from your `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> maybe I use a Profile class to encapsulate the SQL functions instead of my activity?

Not the `Profile` class, no. That is the model. It only stores data, not processes it. You should implement all database-related reading & writing into the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance instead of the Activity. Other example methods could be `boolean contains(String name)`, `List<String> getAllNames()`, and `boolean delete(String name)`.

---

> I'm confused as to whether or not I should have a private `ArrayList<String> mProfileNames` member variable in my activity class, or if I should aim for a `private ArrayList<Profile> mProfiles` member variable in my activity class instead.

If you only have one string (and one column in the database), then there is nothing wrong with only `ArrayList<String>`.

---

> I have to worry about making sure that any time I update the database in any way (adding/removing/etc), I also update the arraylist in the same way

Then only update the database, clear the ArrayList, re-query, and re-populate the list. Don't worry about updating records in the ArrayList.

---

> properly implement MVC practice in this example

Overall, the Activity should only display the data in the ListView (**V**). It calls methods of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` (**C**), which returns data in the form of `Profile` or `String` (**M**) to be displayed.

Comment: I understand that, but I am trying to figure out how to structure everything so it encapsulates the correct functionalities in each piece (in the example that I gave)

Comment: You don't need an ArrayAdapter. You can use a CursorAdapter.

Comment: That doesn't address my actual question. I'm asking about where the functionalities should be encapsulated. The fine details of this adapter vs. that adapter can be adjusted later.

Comment: Let me know if that addresses your questions now.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you. Accepted answer

Comment: Very quick side question: Do you think having the SQL helper object should be instantiated as-needed, or made a private member variable?

Comment: Depends on how you need to use it. I would make it a member variable only if you plan on using it from many methods in the Activity class.

Comment: So if I am only using it to call a function from the helper that returns `ArrayList<String>` then I probably don't need it to be a member variable, would you agree with this?

Comment: Doesn't hurt. The only downside to the non-member variable is that you can't use that variable in other methods.